# NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in custom tag

Tags: jsf, custom-tag

I write a custom tag with JSF 2.0. And use it in my page. When declare it, show the following warning.

```
 NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in:org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

I need to disable it. So, I try many ways. It is not work. Such as, close project -> open project -> build project -> validate project. That also not work. How to solve it. It is a custom tag lib declaration. Thanks.